# How do I access the parameters from json API in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api, parameters

My rails app is receiving the following from the json. How do I access the name key of attributes and the calendar id in Ruby.

```
 Parameters: {"data"=>{"type"=>"user-events", "attributes"=>{"name"=>"An event", "location"=>"University of Illinois at Urbna-Champaign", "notes"=>"Testing my eventf\n", "all-day"=>false, "recurring"=>false, "sunday"=>false, "monday"=>false, "tuesday"=>false, "wednesday"=>false, "thursday"=>false, "friday"=>false, "saturday"=>false, "start-date"=>"01-16-2018", "stop-date"=>"01-16-2018", "start-time"=>"04:32PM", "stop-time"=>"05:32PM"}, "relationships"=>{"calendar"=>{"data"=>{"type"=>"calendars", "id"=>"685"}}}}}
```

Do I use the code below to access the name attribute ?

```
 params[:data][:attributes][:name]
```

Also, do I use the following to access the id for the calendars ?

```
params[:data][:relationships][:calendar][:data][:id]
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Always try before asking any question, if it works for you well and good, if it doesn't, show the wrong output or the error you're getting.

Comment: Yes, it looks fine to me so always try before posting a question

Comment: I get undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass when I use the above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Hash name is Parameters

```
    Parameters['data']['attributes']['name'] # "An event" 
    Parameters['data']['relationships']['calendar']['data']['id'] # "685"
```

if it's params, then

```
    params['data']['attributes']['name'] # "An event" 
    params['data']['relationships']['calendar']['data']['id'] # "685"
```

will access the attributes.